# OPC UA String from Server to Client

Tags: c#, string, int32, opc-ua

I want to send a string from my underlying system through the server to my client. I have made a model in OPCModeler(Unified Automation).

[image: OPC Model in OPCModeler]

And now to connect the underlying system to nodemanager I used the following xml code. The variables with Int32 are allright. 
The strings get the error:

> BadNodeIdUnknown.

```
<UnderlyingSystem.Configuration
xmlns="http://yourcompany.com/underlyingsystem"
xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
 <GModel>
<Name>GMaschine</Name>
<Type>1</Type>
<Properties>
  <Name>actChannelNo</Name>
  <DataType>i=6</DataType>
  <Value>0</Value>
  <Range>0:10000000</Range>
</Properties>
<Properties>
  <Name>axisName</Name>
  <DataType>i=12</DataType>
  <Value>"0"</Value>
  <Writeable>false</Writeable>
</Properties>
<Properties>
  <Name>axisNo</Name>
  <DataType>i=6</DataType>
  <Value>0</Value>
  <Range>0:10000000</Range>
</Properties>
<Properties>
  <Name>axisType</Name>
  <DataType>i=12</DataType>
  <Value>0</Value>
  <Writeable>false</Writeable>
</Properties>
<Properties>
  <Name>cleaningProgramPath</Name>
  <DataType>i=12</DataType>
  <Value>0</Value>
  <Writeable>false</Writeable>
</Properties>
<Properties>
  <Name>connection</Name>
  <DataType>i=12</DataType>
  <Value>0</Value>
  <Writeable>false</Writeable>
</Properties>
<Properties>
  <Name>feed_value</Name>
  <DataType>i=12</DataType>
  <Value>0</Value>
  <Writeable>false</Writeable>
</Properties>
<Properties>
  <Name>guid</Name>
  <DataType>i=12</DataType>
  <Value>0</Value>
  <Writeable>false</Writeable>
</Properties>
<Properties>
  <Name>hardware_SN</Name>
  <DataType>i=12</DataType>
  <Value>0</Value>
  <Writeable>false</Writeable>
</Properties>
<Properties>
  <Name>hardwarePlatform</Name>
  <DataType>i=12</DataType>
  <Value>0</Value>
  <Writeable>false</Writeable>
</Properties>
<Properties>
  <Name>id</Name>
  <DataType>i=12</DataType>
  <Value>0</Value>
  <Writeable>false</Writeable>
</Properties>
<Properties>
  <Name>ipAddress</Name>
  <DataType>i=12</DataType>
  <Value>0</Value>
  <Writeable>false</Writeable>
</Properties>
<Properties>
  <Name>loadUnloadProgramPath</Name>
  <DataType>i=12</DataType>
  <Value>0</Value>
  <Writeable>false</Writeable>
</Properties>
<Properties>
  <Name>location</Name>
  <DataType>i=12</DataType>
  <Value>0</Value>
  <Writeable>false</Writeable>
</Properties>
<Properties>
  <Name>machineReady</Name>
  <DataType>i=1</DataType>
  <Writeable>false</Writeable>
</Properties>
<Properties>
  <Name>motionStatus</Name>
  <DataType>i=12</DataType>
  <Value>0</Value>
  <Writeable>false</Writeable>
</Properties>
<Properties>
  <Name>name</Name>
  <DataType>i=12</DataType>
  <Value>0</Value>
  <Writeable>false</Writeable>
</Properties>
<Properties>
  <Name>platformVersion</Name>
  <DataType>i=12</DataType>
  <Value>0</Value>
  <Writeable>false</Writeable>
</Properties>
<Properties>
  <Name>timezone</Name>
  <DataType>i=12</DataType>
  <Value>0</Value>
  <Writeable>false</Writeable>
</Properties>
<Properties>
  <Name>type</Name>
  <DataType>i=12</DataType>
  <Value>0</Value>
  <Writeable>false</Writeable>
</Properties>
</GModel>
 </UnderlyingSystem.Configuration>
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe a little bit latte but for future reference, the nodeIds are stored in the csv file, not in the xml file.

For each node you have in your xml, you have the corresponding node in the csv. A good place to start is the OPCU Foundation , and you can see the base models here: https://opcfoundation.org/UA/schemas/